# MVCReportViewer Subsequent Requests Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, ssrs-2012, rdl

I am using the [MVCReportViewer](https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer) to display SSRS 2012 reports. I installed via Nuget and it works on initial load. However if I click view, with or without changing parameters, the loading dialog never closes and the report never renders. Inspecting the requests I see a failure in the XHR request. It actually shows status code 200, but inspecting the response yields the following...

**The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file.  Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.**

Here are my httphandler sections...

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <!-- Required by Microsoft ReportViewer control -->
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <!-- Required by Microsoft ReportViewer control -->
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <remove name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" />
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  <system.webServer>
```

I cannot figure out how this works on initial load but fails on these following requests. This works locally on VS 2012 Development Server but on IIS7 fails.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests enabled?

Comment: I did not, but I tried. Same behavior.

Comment: I got it working by adding `EnablePartialRendering="false"` to the `ScriptManager` on the ASPX page. Not sure why that works, but it disables the progress dialog. Not ideal.